# How to make custom error page in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, 2checkout

I want to add custom error page for the below image. This page has to show the error. How can I do that? 
I am using the code given below. In this code I have a try part and a catch part. This code is given by 2checkout. I have tried to return view from the catch part but that didn't work. The same error is coming as shown in image. What could be the solution of it?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\TwoCheckoutAccount;
use File;
//use App\Twocheckout\lib\Twocheckout as Twocheckout;
use Twocheckout;
use Twocheckout_Charge;
use App\Price;
use App\Payment;

class PaymentsController extends Controller
{


    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index($type, $id)
    {
        $twoCheckOut = TwoCheckoutAccount::find(1);
        $price = Price::where('priceable', '=', $type)->firstOrFail();
        return view('payment')->with('twoCheckOut',$twoCheckOut)->with(['type'=>$type, 'id'=>$id, 'price'=>$price->price]);
    }

    public function process(Request $request)
    {
        $twoCheckOut = TwoCheckoutAccount::find(1);
        File::requireOnce(app_path() . "/Twocheckout/lib/Twocheckout.php");
        Twocheckout::verifySSL(false);

        Twocheckout::privateKey($twoCheckOut->private_key);
        Twocheckout::sellerId($twoCheckOut->sellerid);
        if ($twoCheckOut->mode == "sandbox")
             Twocheckout::sandbox(true);

         $payble_product_type = $request->payble_product_type;
         $payble_product_id = $request->payble_product_id;

         $price = Price::where('priceable', '=', $payble_product_type)->firstOrFail();


       try {
        $charge = Twocheckout_Charge::auth(array(
            "merchantOrderId" => ucfirst($payble_product_type)."#".$payble_product_id,
            "token"      => $_POST['token'],
            "currency"   => 'USD',
            "total"      => $price->price,
            "tangible"  => "N",
            "li_#_name" =>  $payble_product_type,

            "billingAddr" => array(
                "name" => $request->purchaser_name,
                "addrLine1" => $request->purchaser_addr1,
                "addrLine2" => $request->purchaser_addr2,
                "city" => $request->purchaser_city,
                "state" => $request->purchaser_state,
                "zipCode" => $request->purchaser_zipcode,
                "country" => $request->purchaser_country,
                "email" => $request->purchaser_email,
                "phoneNumber" => $request->purchaser_phone
            )
        ));

        if ($charge['response']['responseCode'] == 'APPROVED') {
            $payment = new Payment;
            $payment->paymentable_id = $payble_product_id;
            $payment->paymentable_type = "App\\".ucfirst($payble_product_type);
            $payment->transactionId_2co = $charge['response']['transactionId'];
            $payment->order_num_2co = $charge['response']['orderNumber'];
            $payment->responseMsg_2co = $charge['response']['responseMsg'];
            $payment->responseCode_2co = $charge['response']['responseCode'];
            $payment->total_2co = $charge['response']['total'];
            $payment->save();
            return view('payment_confirmation')->with('transId', $payment->transactionId_2co);
        }
    } catch (Twocheckout_Error $e) {print_r($e->getMessage());}

    }


}
```

[image]

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/errors#render-method

Comment: where should I have to write it, in controller?

Comment: Read the entire page I linked you. Particularly the "All exceptions are handled by the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class" bit.

Comment: I tried the code in Handler. But it didn't work.. also created a file 2check.blade.php in errors folder. Am I not getting it right? 

`public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof Twocheckout_Error ) {
          return response()->view('errors.2check', [], 500);
        }

        if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
            $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
        }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}`

Comment: Thanks @ceejayoz... problem was in using /Twocheckout_Error... Global namespace :)